# Can OpenMPI or MPICH integrate with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mpi

I am new to MPi and parallel computing, I am wondering if MPICH or OpenMpi can integrate with Nodejs?
Thanks all.

Comment: You can write bridge code that allows you to make MPI calls from Node. There are tons of MPI library calls, so it won't be easy, but it should be doable.

Comment: I agree with @HristoIliev when he states *it should be doable*.  I would add that is an ambitious project for someone new to MPI and parallel computing.  I expect that the bridge code he suggests might best be written in C.